# mciSendString() doesn't play audio files that have cover art

Tags: c++, winapi, mp3, audio-player, mci

I am making a music player, and I decided to use `mciSendString()`, and it worked just fine!

#### The issue is:

If the song I want to play has cover art, no music plays. If I manually remove the cover art using something like MP3tag, it then plays fine.

```cpp
song = playlist.get(songnum); //this changes song which is a value holding a path from the old song to the path of the new song
command = mcicommand(song, "c", volume); //send back the new path to the function command to make us the new command to use in mcisend string
mciSendString(command.c_str(), NULL, 0, NULL);

string mcicommand(string path, string voc, string volume) {

    if (voc == "c") { //Play Command

        string command = "open type mpegvideo alias song"; //the template for the open command we will use

        int found = command.find(" "); //finds the first space in the template

        command = command.substr(0, found) + " \"" + path + "\"" + command.substr(found); //adds the stuff before the first space then the path after the first space then second space then everything after that second space

        return command; //returns the command which we will use in mcisend string
    }

    if (voc == "v") { //Volume command

        string command = "setaudio song volume to "; //same as the one before just with a different command string

        int found = command.find_last_of(" ");
        command = command.substr(0, found) + " " + volume;

        return command;
    }

}
```

So far, I used FFmpeg to read the info of the music files, and found out that the cover art is sort of defined as a track? So my assumption is that `mciSendString()` is trying to play the cover art instead of the actual audio track?

I cannot really decipher the documentations to understand how I can fix this.

#### Extra Info

Song that didn't played noise:

```
 Input #0, mp3, from 'Golden.mp3':
  Metadata:
                    : major_brand
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:01:54.08, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 138 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64
  Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 400x225, 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      title           : attached picture
      comment         : Cover (front)
```

Song that played noise:

```
 Input #0, mp3, from 'HeatAFire.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:03:59.05, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
```

Comment: Does the problem happen with all MP3 files that contain *any* ID3v2 tags, or is it just MP3s that have cover art *specifically*? The original MP3 format didn't support tagging at all, and ID3v1 was at least backwards compatible with old players that don't understand ID3v1, but ID3v2 is not backwards compatible with old players. [What are ID3 Tags in MP3 Files?](https://www.richardfarrar.com/what-are-id3-tags-in-mp3-files/)  MCI is old tech, so I'm guessing maybe it simply can't handle ID3v2 tags? Consider using a more modern multimedia API instead.

Comment: Maybe video stream cause it. Try removing it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is only Mp3 files with cover songs to them, other ID3v2 tags don't cause problems

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT How would I do that in code? and will it cause issues such as edit the actual Mp3 file because that may be problematic if someone uses it and all of a sudden all their covers go missing

Comment: @Enigmacoder "will it cause issues such as edit the actual Mp3 file because that may be problematic if someone uses it and all of a sudden all their covers go missing" - That's something *you* need to figure out.

Comment: @EnigmaCoder Sorry. I cannot reproduce the issue. I even used `mciSendString` to play a video successfully! Check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fMP4.png. So my conclusion is the type of your song file had changed or not adding absolute path cause it cannot play normally. Please check the file and add the absolute path just as my code: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/6470be1633a3ae27016f4f4bbcf0a518. If it still does not funtion, delete the \\ to used `mciGetErrorString` to get the error code. I'm Waiting for your feedback.